# Runtime error. Trying to generate random ints

Tags: java, compilation, runtime-error

I am trying to run this program but am getting a strange runtime error message (a runtime error) where the I get a pop up window with a yellow exclamation point and a the Java coffee cup.  The message reads "The Java class file Account.class could not be launched.  Check console for possible error messages."  I have checked the console but don't see any errors.  Can anyone see whats wrong with this program? Thanks so much for all the help.  I am using BlueJ on a Mac to write, compile, and run this program.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class ArrayDemo
{
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    System.out.println("Begin Program");
    int arr[] = new int[100];
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
}

public static int[] calculateEven ( int[]a )
{
    int arr[] = new int[100];
    int idx = 0;

    for ( int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
    {
        if (a[j]%2==0)
        {
            arr[idx] = a[j];
            idx++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

public static int[] calculateOdd ( int[]b )
{
    int arr[] = new int [100];
    int idx = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < b. length; i++)
    {
        if (b[i]%2!=0)
        {
            arr[idx] = b[i];
            idx++;   
        }   
    }
    return arr;
 }   
}
```

Comment: There's no runtime error from that code. It must be a problem with your environment.

Comment: @resueman It compiles and runs and generates then prints the number on your machine?

Comment: It doesn't print any number (since your code never calls either of the `calculate` methods right now (although I did add a bit of code to call them to make sure they ran)), but it prints the "Begin Program" message, and exits successfully.

Comment: It runs fine. Make sure you run it a Java Application. Where are you getting the Account Class from ? Try running the program in Eclipse. Most people use that and will be able to help you out quickly.

Comment: @resueman Doesn't my program return the calculateodd and calculateeven arrays at the end of each method? What additional code would I need to add to get it to print correctly?

Comment: @Skier1999 You'd need to call those methods inside your `main` method (ie. `int[] evens = calculateEven(arr);`). Right now you just declare them, but never use them anywhere.

Comment: @Skier1999 You can check the code I wrote. Works fine. Changed your main method and the way you handle the random number generator.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Thank you for the code below, but I added a comment because I am still confused.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

It will first print out the even numbers followed by the odd numbers.

Added method calls in the main method and properly declared and used the random number generator.

Works fine. But will print trailing 0's as you declared the size of the arrays to 100 inside the two methods you call , and they do not have that many values.

```
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    System.out.println("Begin Program");

    int arr[] = new int[100];
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i ++){
        arr[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
    int even[] = calculateEven (arr);
    int odd[] =  calculateOdd (arr);

    System.out.println("Printing Even");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < even.length; i ++){
        System.out.println(even[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Printing Odd");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < odd.length; i ++){
        System.out.println(odd[i]);
    }
}

public static int[] calculateEven ( int[]a )
{
    int arr[] = new int[100];
    int idx = 0;


    for ( int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
    {
        if (a[j]%2==0)
        {
            arr[idx] = a[j];
            idx++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

public static int[] calculateOdd ( int[]b )
{
    int arr[] = new int [100];
    int idx = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < b. length; i++)
    {
        if (b[i]%2!=0)
        {
            arr[idx] = b[i];
            idx++;   
        }   
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: This program only seems to print 0s on my machine.  How come it does that and not just do what the program was intended to do? Create randoms then sort then print them? Thanks for all the help but I still don't understand why mine isn't working correctly

Comment: @Skier1999 Try the following link. http://goo.gl/Us18kK . First Compile and then execute. Then check the output. Hope it helps. You can get the entire code there.